# Find n indices such that their sum is equal to k, and the sum of the elements at these indices is minimal

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

You are given **n** arrays. Each consists of non-negative integers in ascending order. You need to find **n** indices such that their sum is equal to **k**, and the sum of the elements in these arrays at the found indices is minimal.

Example 1:

```py
a = [0, 3, 5, 7, 10]
b = [0, 5]
c = [0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 18]
k = 7
 
ans = [3, 0, 4] # a[3] + b[0] + c[4] is minimized.
# sum of indices is equal to k
# sum of elements is 20, which is minimum possible
```

Example 2:

```py
a = [0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10]
b = [0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 10]
c = [0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9 ]
k = 10

ans = [5, 1, 4] # Minimum sum = 18 (10 + 1 + 7)
```

I've tried choosing min element at each step, but that doesn't seem to work. Any efficient approach rather than checking all combinations of indices?

edit: Looks like greedy approaches won't work at all. Maybe it is about dp, which looks something similar to `dp[k][j]` - minimum sum if we pick indices that sum up to **k**, considering first **j** arrays. Then the answer is `dp[k][n]`. That's my assumption, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Could definitely clarify how "choosing min element at each step... doesn't seem to work" but I suspect a similar greedy approach is expected unless the constraints are small enough to the point where a brute-force approach would be feasible.

Comment: Would dynamic programming on `k` be a solution?

Comment: I think it's the dp, but I have no idea how to calculate it. It would be nice if we could solve this problem for every value of k from 0 to k, however this seems impossible in polynomial time to me.

Comment: @wLui155 greedy may also work. But in provided example chossing min element wont lead us to the correct answer

Comment: Modify the greedy approach so that you step towards the next element based on the difference between it and the current. For example if you've got `A = [100, 101], B = [1, 11]` with `k = 1`, you'd start with picking `A[0], B[0]` and decide to pick `A[1]` over `B[1]` because the difference between `A[1] - A[0] < B[1] - B[0]`, despite `A[1] > B[1]`.

Comment: @wLui155 so if we choose A[1], the resulting sum will be 101, but the answer will be 11 (B[1]). And also what to do if A[1] - A[0] == B[1] - B[0]? Check indexes 2 and 1? But there are also examples that make this approach wrong :(

Comment: Didn't realize that you could pick multiple indices from a single array at the same time. That makes things a bit harder and might be helpful to put in the description.

Comment: @wLui155 sorry for misunderstanding, each index each index belongs to its own array. One index per array. I meant that if the difference between the elements is equal, we need to check next pairs

Comment: Yes it looks like the dp scheme you propose should work.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that would be great, but I have no idea how to calculate it

Comment: I think the modified greedy approach would work then. The answer would be `A[1] + B[0] = 102`, which is better than picking `A[0] + B[1] = 111`. Basically the greedy approach should work since you're adding the minimal delta to the current sum while getting the sum of indices one-more-closer to `k`.

Comment: I swap around indices in your scheme for better readability so that the answer is in `dp[n][k]`. Now for `i` in `0..k` `dp[1][i]` is just `array[1][i]`, and `dp[m][i] = min (dp[m-1][0]+array[m][i], dp[m-1][1]+array[m][i-1], ..., dp[m-1][i]+array[m][0])` (sum of indices is `i`).

Comment: @wLui155 I thought A[0] == 0, sorry. Check the case `a = [0, 6, 7]`, `b = [0, 5, 8]` and `k = 2`. `a[1] - a[0] > b[1] - b[0]`, so we take `b[1]`. Then we continue: `a[1] - a[0] > b[2] - b[1]`, so we move b pointer and now it is `b[2]`. `0 + 2 = k`. Then the answer is `b[2]` which is 8? No, the answer is `a[2]` which is 7. This looks counterintuitive at first.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thx for response, but what if len(arr) < k? then we can't access `arr[i]` where i <= k. And also how do we recover the solution?

Comment: Then you just do not include it in the `min` expression (or equivalently imagine that all array[i][j] = infinity when j is outside the array bounds).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI omg!!!! it passing stress tests! thank you, but how do we get the indices at the end?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI our initial task was to find these indices. in example 1 the answer is `[3, 0, 4]`. But I think I managed to solve it. Anyway, thanks

Comment: Ah I see. You will need to associate a set of indices to each dp[i][j] then, in addition to the sum. Not very difficult.